# Git: Merge Multiple Branches

Tags: git, git-gui

I apologise if this has been answered somewhere thoroughly, obvious and many times as it likely already has; but I've been unable to find information on this specific problem I'm having after searching for at least a week.

To simplify we have 3 people working on a project, each person has their own branch which we are regularly going to merge back into the master trunk. The problem is that we either get conflicts (attempting to cherry pick) or it simply seems to overwrite all the files of the master and the first 2 branches merged with the last one, effectively merging nothing, just overwriting.

My problem is (hopefully) simply:

Master trunk

```
string test1;
string test2;
string test3;
```

test1 branch

```
 string test1 = "Dan Branch merged";
 string test2;
 string test3;
```

test2 branch

```
string test1;
string test2 = "Dave Branch merged";
string test3;
```

test3 branch

```
string test1;
string test2;
string test3 = "Will Branch merged";
```

Desired output when all 3 branches are merged:

```
string test1 = "Dan Branch merged";
string test2 = "Dave Branch merged";
string test3 = "Will Branch merged";
```

What I actually get when I try to merge test 1 and 2 is:

Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

```
  <<<<<<< HEAD
 +        String test1 = "Dan Branch merged";
 +        String test2;
 +        String test3;
  =======
+         String test1;
+         String test2 = "Dave Branch merged.";
+         String test3;
  >>>>>>> test2
```

I am currently using git-gui on Windows (with the plan of changing to the bash/shell/cli when I've finally got my head around git) so if it all possible it'd be great if any answers were given specifically for git-gui, but of course beggars can't be choosers.

Trying to keep things simple the repository is on a local network folder and not any server. I don't know if this affects the implementation (I'd imagine push and pull would be unused if I've guessed their usage correctly)

Currently Git has been relegated to just being a method to store and browse old versions as all merging is being done by hand.

Comment: Do you cherry-pick, because the 3 contributors won't merge all their commits in the master or is it because you don't know any alternative to it?

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt I don't know any alternatives. We all work regulated hours, during those hours we all get the current master trunk and work on different sections of it.

If we try to merge all of them back into the master trunk one by one it seems to just overwrite the merged-into branch with the merging branch.

Comment: after merging a branch to master, do you commit after resolving the conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle your code might not be the regular way to handle distributed developing. I'd recommend (if access to master trunk is available during developing) the following steps to make this work:

```
git stash     (to put your changes away for the moment)
git pull      (to get the latest commits)
git stash pop (to get back, what was stashed away in the first step)
```

Then resolve the conflict you have. This should be not as much as when merging a whole branch. Then:

```
git commit
git push
```

**Important:** Avoid changing the branch and work on master. Branches are more often used to develop things in parallel, that aren't commited every day to master. E.g. when starting a new, major version of a software, that changes much of the old code or api, so that you can't simply push them to master, because the commit would unstabilize the whole package.

Edit:

To honorate David's comment: It's no harm in using branches in git, but I had one or two cases, where unproperly handled branches lead to confusions, that an unexperienced git user had a hard time to understand and resolve. Those handling mistake shouldn't be usual, though.

Edit:

As it turns out you really do have only one local repository alltogether. It seemed to me, that you have a LAN repository you all push to, at first. So if you don't change your infrastructure (I don't recommend it. An alternative would be http://bitbucket.org and everyone with his own repository clone on his computer) then there is (I think) no other way then in having three branches. I strongly recommend to you, that you read a git tutorial like http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html in order to change your infrastructure. Good Luck with it.

Comment: Branches are cheap in Git. What's the harm in branching if it all gets merged back into master anyway?

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt Thank you for your time and assistance. We're using a local network folder to keep things simple (I added that via an edit shortly before your first comment so you likely read the old version). I'm assuming those are for if you have a server setup. If I'm right could you please give instruction for what is effectively a local setup? Once again, thank you.

Comment: @Daemeous Can I help you in any other way?

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt Sorry, I pressed enter to create a new line, but it instead posted the comment, I finished editing it.

Comment: @Daemeous sry, but if you don't have a specific question, it will be quite hard to explain git handling in a short answer without knowing, what you know about git and what of it you don't. E.g. it's unclear in which way you use cherry-pick, but my guess is that you don't need it and by this should be fine with git merge -> resolve conflict -> commit all and push it, then the next contributor can do the same. Again, sry that I can't help you more.

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt I've tried using cherry-pick and merge, cherry pick was something I read somewhere else to try.

To put simply I'm trying to find a way to merge 3 "branches" of one trunk together in a local (LAN) repository.

The 3 of us all copy the current master copy and work on 3 seperate parts (engine, the UI and mechanics). We want a way to merge all 3 branches back into the master keeping all of our changes (we will likely edit the same file but not the same line).

I don't understand what push and pull methods do, what I understand is they're used for server repos.

Comment: @Daemeous ? How do you exchange the code, somewhere there must be a computer in your LAN, that all of you can access and where the repository lies.

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt It's a local repository on a shared network folder, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Daemeous and how does one of you update the code in this repository?

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt We checkout our branch, then replace the code in there, stage the changes and commit.

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt The plan was to eventually swap to a server based architecture, but the current setup was to try to keep things simple and learn git. Would using the commands you initially posted solve our issue if we changed to the standard server architecture?

Comment: @Daemeous my first post was in fact meant for a server based solution. Generally you should be fine, if you follow my first post when adding new code to the repository.

Comment: @ChristophEberhardt Thank you for your massive help and sorry for my inability to convey what I was actually do it. Also sorry for the late reply this time we just had an internet outage, marked as answer.